# Cannot Connect to Firebase From Android Studio using Firebase Assistant

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

I do have problem in connecting to Firebase from Android Studio using Firebase Assistant. It just popup this image when i try to connect to Firebase. I'm quite new to Firebase and Android Development so this is a little problem to me.

[image]

[image]

This is my build.gradle for project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com

.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google- 
services:4.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application 
dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is my build.gradle (App)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.thebooksmart.booksmart"
       minSdkVersion 23
       targetSdkVersion 28
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
       testInstrumentationRunner 
  "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
         release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles 
           getDefaultProguardFile('proguard- 
           android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
       }
     }

    dependencies {
       implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs',include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
   }
     apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Requesting help from experts or anyone that know how to sort this